# Is there a way to change the close icons on the autocomplete component of material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I would like to change the icon, but would like to keep the function when clicking.
is there a good solution for this?

[I want to change this Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkMHS.png)

```
<Autocomplete
      multiple
      id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      disableCloseOnSelect
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Checkbox
            icon={icon}
            checkedIcon={checkedIcon}
            style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            checked={selected}
          />
          {option.title}
        </React.Fragment>
      )}
      style={{ width: 500 }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" label="Checkboxes" placeholder="Favorites" />
      )}
    />
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a function to customize the rendering of the Chip component used by the Autocomplete

```
<Autocomplete
    multiple
    id="tags-filled"
    options={top100Films.map((option) => option.title)}
    defaultValue={[top100Films[13].title]}
    freeSolo
    renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
      value.map((option, index) => (
        <Chip variant="outlined" label={option} {...getTagProps({ index })} />
      ))
    }
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField {...params} variant="filled" label="freeSolo" placeholder="Favorites" />
    )}
  />
```

And the Chip component can be further customized with the `deleteIcon` prop

Edit: For more info, see [the API of the Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#multiple-values) and [the API of the Chip](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using the `ChipProps` of Autocomplete, as that icon is a part of a [Chip](https://material-ui.com/api/chip/) component, and can be customized through `deleteIcon` property

Comment: Can you  please mention an example for this?